# Ordering based on 2 separate join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to grab a total list of all of the products available ordered by stores and the time the user joined the store, so that the users most recently joined store's products are listed first then so on. Noting that all products need to be shown, whether or not that user belongs to that store(those would be shown last and are of least priority).

```
Class User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :stores, through: :memberships

  has_many :active_memberships, -> {active}, class_name: "Membership"
  has_many :active_stores, through: :active_memberships
end

Class Store
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships

  has_many :active_memberships, -> {active}, class_name: "Membership"
  has_many :active_users, through: :active_memberships

  has_and_belongs_to_many :products,  association_foreign_key: :product_id
end

Class Membership
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :stores

  scope :active, -> {where(active: true).order(:created_at)}
end

Class Product
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores,
    join_table:           :product_stores,
    foreign_key:          :product_id
end
```

Here is what I have gotten to so far.

```
user = User.find(1)
ids = user.active_stores.ids
subscribed_store_products = Product.joins(stores: :memberships).where("stores.id = Any({#{ids}) AND memberships.user_id = 1").order("memberships.created_at")

non_susbscribed_store_products = Product.joins(:stores).where("stores.id != Any({#{ids})")
```

Then merge the two accordingly to receive a list. I wanted to know if there may be something that I am missing.

Comment: What do you mean my ordered by stores?

Comment: I want to pull all of the products, but have them be listed so that any products that belong to a store that I am subscribed to are listed first (prefer to have products ordered by the date that the user joined the store).